# How to output more than one column

Tags: csv, lua

I want to process a data file like this:

```
2015-02-23  190   170   131   14  8   9   130 85  102.0   12  68
2015-02-24  165   128   97    14  7   6   110 75  101.7   12  64
2015-02-25  160   123   129   11  5   7   130 85  101.3   12  68
2015-02-26  151   115   128   11  nan 7   120 80  100.9   12  64
2015-02-27  141   119   130   11  4   nan 130 85  101.6   12  68
2015-02-28  142   137   143   nan nan nan 120 80  101.2   12  64
```

and to output **some** columns.

So far I managed:

```
local infile = arg[1]
local outfile = arg[2]
local column = tonumber(arg[3])
local data = {}
local row = 0
local ofile

for line in io.lines(infile)
do
  row = row + 1
  data[row] = {}
  local i = 0
  for value in string.gmatch(line, "%S+") do
    i = i + 1
    data[row][i] = value
  end
end

ofile = assert(io.open(outfile, "w"))
for i = 1,row do
  ofile:write(data[i][column] .. "\n")
end
ofile:close()
```

This works fine for one column: `lua column.lua test.dat new.dat 2`

```
190
165
160
151
141
142
```

What I would like to have is `lua column.lua test.dat new.dat 1,2,4` to have columns 1, 2 and 4 in the new file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function to extract a list of columns:

```
function cols(t, colnums, prefix)
  -- get the number of the first column and the rest of the numbers
  -- it splits 1,2,3 into 1 and 2,3
  local col, rest = colnums:match("^(%d+)[,%s]*(.*)")
  -- if nothing is provided return current `prefix` value (may be `nil`)
  if not col then return prefix end
  -- convert the string with the column number into number
  -- this is needed because t[1] and t['1'] references different values
  local val = t[tonumber(col)]
  -- call the same function recursively, but using the rest of the columns
  -- this also concatenates the prefix (if any) with the current value
  return cols(t, rest, prefix and prefix.."\t"..val or val)
end
```

Now instead of `ofile:write(data[i][column] .. "\n")`, you can use `ofile:write(cols(data[i], arg[3]) .. "\n")`. Since it does parsing on every row, it may be inefficient for a large number of rows, so if that's the case for you, you'll probably need to parse it once at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I'll try to understand your code. The built-in lua interpretator i quite new for us TeX guys! ;-) Can you elaborate a bit on the code, as I really want to understand?

Comment: Sure; I added comments to the example.

Comment: Without recursion: `cols = assert(load("return table.concat({"..arg[3]:gsub("%d+","(...)[%0]").."},'\\t')"))`, usage: `ofile:write(cols(data[i]).."\n")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, clever!